# Solaris SMF for Oracle DB is ok but not for the Listener. How can an SMF method work under svcadm but not to restart the service when it has failed?

Tags: oracle, listener, manifest, solaris, smf

I have 2 questions about Solaris SMF. (I am an SMF newbie.)

I set up the Oracle RDBMS service in SMF as per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61677/odbstartstop.html

The database part works entirely as expected, so I added a *listener* as another service instance seeing as the method script has an option of 'listener' as an argument instead of 'db' and will run a `lsnrctl start ${LISTENER}`  instead of using `sqlplus` to access and then start or stop a database instance.

The *svcadm enable* and *svcadm disable* of the service start and stop the *listener* as expected. The issue is that the framework senses if `lsnrctl` is running but does nothing to restart it, if it has stopped. See below:

```
svc:/site/oracle/db/oracle12lsnr:LISTENER4 (?)
 State: maintenance since May 21, 2020 03:25:39 PM BST
Reason: Method failed.
   See: http://support.oracle.com/msg/SMF-8000-8Q
   See: /var/svc/log/site-oracle-db-oracle12lsnr:LISTENER4.log
Impact: This service is not running.
```

The - **Reason: Method failed.** - is not congruent with the fact that invoking the method via **svcadm enable** (or **disable**) shows that the method works just fine.

Further investigation - I killed the **lsnrctl** process from root and got this from **svcs -Lv**

```
[ May 22 14:13:30 Executing stop method ("/lib/svc/method/svc-oracle12-database lsnr stop LISTENER4"). ]
LSNRCTL for Solaris: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 22-MAY-2020 14:13:30
Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orahost.some.domain)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Solaris Error: 146: Connection refused
[ May 22 14:13:30 Method "stop" exited with status 95. ]
```

So the first question has changed and is now: Why would it run the stop method? The ***db*** version of this service runs the **start** method when the database service goes down.

Answer to Q1: the service framework runs the stop method followed by the start method. Once this was established a fresh look at the method script revealed a flaw. It error exited in the stop method if it couldn't contact the tnslsnr process. (Logic fail. If the tnslsnr process was killed you can't test a connection to it!)

To be honest I am struggling with the sheer volume of information to get through. I am currently reading through the pdf version of the URL above. I had a quick look here at Moellenkamp's blog http://blog.moellenkamp.org/archives/18-Auditing-a-single-SMF-service-revisted.html but I've not implemented that auditing service yet - assuming it would help anyway. If anyone has any thoughts as to why this isn't working I'd be really grateful.

The second question is this:

In the example the manifest is stored in `/lib/svc/manifest/site/oracle/db` and *first time around* I changed this to `/lib/svc/manifest/site/oracle12db` since 2 subdirectories (after .../site) seemed a little over the top and this resulted in the service just failing to work in any way (always in maintenance). I ***had*** adjusted the manifest xml file to match the changed directory structure. I was baffled and after fiddling around I simply changed the xml files and directory structure to match the example and it all worked. Why would that be? Is there some formula to the layers in the **service_name** or **service_bundle**?

I haven't yet read anything that says the directory structure has to be extended as per the example. I had not typo'd the xml file as far as I can tell - especially as revoking the changes to match the original example was simply to alter the service_name and service_bundle lines to match the extended directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To diagnose the reason for a service failure, always start with the service log, path for which is in the svcs output.  Or just use "svcs -Lv " to display it directly.

Comment: Helpful ! Thank you. Pulling the log name with svcs -xv was always a pain.
I tried killing the tnslsnr and then running this immediately. I can now see the relevant messages really quickly and though it might seem trivial it's been an eye opener!

Answer (score 1):

Another 'easy when you know how'.
Upon failure the framework runs the stop method followed by the start method.

I can now scan through the pdf and look to confirm this and also such things as *restart* and *refresh*.
I'll vote for user13596356's response because the quick turnaround on checking the log and a bit of input from an SMF question by user40330 from 7 yrs ago got me looking at the service method script which was flawed.